# Avoid overriding by css

Tags: css, wordpress

I have created a UI (for wordpress plugin) in which I give user choice to add text, image, and video in a `div` ( lets call this `div`, `container`).

I have been working on it for a quite sometime. I recently added `tinyMCE` (`WYSIWYG` editor)  to add text inside `container`.

Now, I realized that I did a big mistake. The text user writes is being overridden by css rules defined for wp admin panel.

for example,

User enters `<h1>Hello</h1>` (with the help of tinyMCE), and then I grab that content from tinyMCE and append that in the `container`.

But here the problem arises, wordpress's admin css can have css rule like this,

```
h1 {
 color : #d6d6d6;
 line-height: 40px;
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

So, it looks different in tinyMCE and in my `container`. (as tinyMCE's code is inside `iframe` and that remains unaffected by wordpress's css rules, but my `container` doesnt)

I want something so that any element inside `container` remains unaffected by wordpress's admin css.

I know a good solution would be putting `container` inside `iframe`. But I have written a lot of code without thinking of an `iframe` and I would need 3-4 days just to adjust everything for `iframe`. There may be some cross browser issues.

I can reset some wordpress rules, but it will fail sometimes, as user may enter anything. I need something fullproof.

Comment: no. css does not let you exempt things from a rule, e.g. ` .container[where not a sub of .othercontainer]`.

Comment: So, what should I do now ? :O

Comment: Good question. I've faced this problem before, and never really had a great solution for it. Best of luck on it.

Comment: @Jashwant does this plugin have its own page?

Comment: No. In wordpress, all plugins are opened in same page `admin.php`,(differentiated by querysting) e.g. `admin.php?page=myplugin`

Answer (score 1):

well if you want to undo a specific rule (say the h1 rule you mentioned) you can use css to override it by being more specific.

```
.container h1 {
    color:#000000;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

This will overwrite the css rule you mentioned with the given values but only when the element is inside the container class, (I'm guessing at the default values you want to use.)

Unfortunately you would have to add in an undo rule for everything that wordpress's admin css changes.

Comment: I have already mentioned this that I can do this, but user may enter anything, so I wont work always

Comment: it will if you add in a rule to undo everything that wordpress does.... but that would be an insane amount of work to setup.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to edit the page tinyMCE returns in it's frame to add in wordpress's CSS file.  This means the end user will see the same formatting when they enter the information as when it gets posted.

Do you have code-level access to the iframe contents tinyMCE creates?

Answer (score 0):

Use !important in your CSS document. This way your CSS will not be overridden as it takes precence over everything, including inline styles.

```
h1 {
    color:#ff0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I have clearly written that `I can reset some wordpress rules, but it will fail sometimes, as user may enter anything`.